# C++ Specifier between definition and declaration

Tags: c++, oop

I got the following declaration:

```
// file MadaPacket.h
class MadaPacket
{
// ....
public:
  inline static bool word_is_header(int w);
}
```

And as the correspondent declaration:

```
// file MadaPacket.cpp
#include "MadaPacket.h"

inline bool MadaPacket::word_is_header(int w)
{
    return w == 0xFBBA;
}
```

MSVC12 builder fails at linkage, with the following reason:

> unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl MadaPacket::word_is_header(int)

Adding `static` to definition pushes error

> 'static' should not be used on member functions defined at file scope

Removing `inline` from definition pushes error

> unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl MadaPacket::word_is_header(int)

I guess I'm misunderstanding some of the definition-declaration relationship.

**EDIT**

Obviously I'd like to have both the modifiers, if this is possible ofc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: A bit general as a "duplicate".

Comment: Yeah, it's more of a *here's the answer, you can close this question now*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `inline` keyword from both places.

The `inline` keyword should be used only when defining functions in header files that are included from multiple translation units. Well, there are other situations where it can be used too, but here none of them apply.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have an *identical* list of modifiers for your definition in your `.h` file and your `.cpp` file. Both definitions should be exactly the same for the linker to find them. So I'd first remove 'static' from both and recompile.

Comment: Surely `static` in the declaration is fine?

Comment: @Biffen Not when it doesn't match the other declaration. `static` appears on only one. They have to match exactly.

Comment: Except for `static` which *should* be in the declaration and *shouldn't* be in the definition.